# how to re-direct posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress and I have 9 sticky posts on my home page

when someone clicks on one of these posts I don't want the post to open

I want to open a nother page (a category to be specific) so can you tell me how to do that ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you would need to modify the  to point towards the category of that post instead.

Your home page can be set on index.php and home.php. I would recommend creating a template page instead and a new page and linking that template to it. That way you will leave index.php and home.php intact for fallback situations.

If you want it dynamic you can view the category codex here:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link

Answer (score 0):

In your loop run a conditional to the category instead of the permalink if is_sticky is true.

A lot of themes contain a loop.php file that contains all the conditionals etc.  The basic premise is:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php
$category_id = get_cat_ID($post->ID);
$category_link = get_category_link($category_id);

if (is_sticky() { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>" title="<?php the_title();"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php } else { ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php } ?>
```